# Is it possible to install a ROM on /recovery instead of /system?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, custom-roms, rom, partitions

I am not going to do it, but I just wonder whether it is possible to install a ROM to /recovery and TWRP to /system, so one would normally boot into TWRP and only boot into Android when one performs the key combination for recovery mode. Is this possible somehow and would it have any negative side effects?

Comment: Well since recovery partition size is usually 16mb then no it's not possible. Maybe you still can resize the partitions in order to fit a system on it, but question is would it work in practice, however it is possible but probably would be great pain in the ass and it's unnecessary to do so why bother with that.

Comment: It is possible to resize the partitions, but there's a large risk to brick your phone this way if you do it wrong. Let's say, one can manage to repartition the storage correctly and would install a ROM on /recovery instead of /system. However, the question is: Would it work properly?

Comment: Probably not, or if you want to make it work it would require a lot of customisation so it's not worth it. However see answer below maybe I was wrong about a way to do what you wanted to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TWRP normally installs to `recovery`; kernel for the OS normally installs to `boot`; `/system` is another thing entirely where the majority of the files of the OS goes.

Doesn't change the conclusion for what you want to achieve though - yes, you *can* swap `boot` and `recovery` so it boots to recovery by default and boots to the OS when choosing "reboot to recovery" or using the key combo. At heart the two booting processes are both simply booting a kernel image. Note that this doesn't touch `/system`.

Comment: So you mean for a regular phone, one can swap `/boot` and `/recovery` to achieve what you said?

Comment: For what I've read, yes, if you can flash a recovery image to `boot` and boot image to `recovery` then the two will be swapped. Disclaimer: I never tried it on my own devices so take some caution.